# Not able to get saved value from db mysql as selected value in dropdown. I trying to update the form which user has already filled

Tags: php

I am trying to get data from database all values are reflecting good but saved value for dropdown is not coming selected.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                        <select name="OfficeName" id="OfficeName" class="form-control"  onchange="getText(this)" required>
            <?php 
            while($data = dbFetchAssoc($result)){
            ?>

            <option value=''><?php echo $data['off_name']; ?></option>
            <?php 
            }//while
            ?>
            </select>   
 </div>
```

Comment: Show us your code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please provide more details. We dont know what your issue is. If you can explain what you are doing we can try to help you fix the problem.

Comment: I have simple signup form which have one drop down with office name for example A,B,C when user sign-up suppose value B is chosen from drop down .B is saved to DB once user click the button.Now if  user edit the data I repopulate fields all the other values are coming but drop down value not coming as DB saved value. I want B option to be selected value once user edit the form again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue.

Let's say you have a select statement that is populated with key value pairs from a database:

```
<select name="sel">
<?php foreach ($options as $value => $label) : ?>
<option value="<?= $value ?>"><?= htmlentities($label) ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

When the form is submitted, you'll get the value of **sel** in $_GET or $_POST (or $_REQUEST).

```
<?php
$selected = $_POST['sel'];
?>
```

To select the corresponding option, update the above code like so:

```
<select name="sel">
<?php foreach ($options as $value => $label) : ?>
<option <?php if ($selected == $value) : ?>selected<?php endif ?> value="<?= $value ?>">
<?= htmlentities($label) ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: This is not helpful I am newbie in php please tell me this with help of while loop.